# Visual Studio 2010 - local history feature?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

The last few years I've been using Eclipse as an IDE. Recently, however, I started working with Visual Studio 2010 and I'm intuitively searching for features I used in Eclipse.

One such is the Local file history. Is there some extension or addon which provides such functionality ?

Another small feature that I'm missing is that I can't just double click on a window to enlarge it, then just double click again and shrink it.

Comment: Could you explain what the feature does? Then people who know VS, but not Eclipse, might be able to help you.

Comment: jaff, the local file history in Eclipse is something that allows you to check all the changes you've made to a particular file, diff the revisions and revert if necessary. It's a really cool feature.

Comment: Why not use a proper source control system for that, though?

Comment: Because it's too heavy, something I want simply to revert a small change which is not necessary too important to add it in the source control. At least from my perspective.

Comment: No. Just no. Using source control is never ever ever ever ever "too heavy". IF you ever have a need to go back to an earlier version of the code, that means the code is important enough to store in version control. If you feel that is "too heavy", investigate other version control systems. In particular, DVCS'es are generally ridiculously easy to set up due to their distributed nature. There is *nothing* heavy about setting up a Hg or Bzr repository.

Comment: @jalf Delphi also has this local history feature, and it saved me couple of times, one was when I accidentally erased shelveset from TFS or when I deleted my source file. I 100% with you on source control usage, everyone should use one, but people make errors, stupid errors and local code history can be life saver.

Comment: @jalf I wouldn't say using a VCS is too heavy but I would say that it's missing a critical feature that Local History in Eclipse and RubyMine does have: automation. Using a VCS for this requires that the user go to command line and check in constantly. My solution below attempts to address this shortcoming.

Comment: That's a very good point

Comment: Came here as a IntelliJ user looking for some of the features I miss so much in VS. If anyone doubts the usefulness of this feature have a look here: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/local_history.html. @jalf "No. Just no." - have you never been pressing ctrl-z in a file hoping to revert some change, but find that you're already at the end of the undo history. Yep, you just realised you miss the local history goodness.

Answer (score 5):

Not a great answer, but after looking around for this feature and not finding it I decided to build my own. Couldn't get the tool on Codeplex to work with VS2010. Anyway, [this post](http://blog.ninlabs.com/2011/10/building-a-visual-studio-history-extension-part-2/) was very helpful and got me on the road to a DIY solution. Note that this assumes that you are *not* using git as your primary VCS. I suppose if you're using git as primary then you'll want to use mercurial as your 'history' source control.

Steps:

1. install git
2. init an empty git repo in the same folder as your solution.
3. create a VS extensibility project (see post above)
4. put this to the OnAfterSave:

   m_RDT.GetDocumentInfo(docCookie, out flags, out readlocks, out editlocks, out name, out hier, out itemid, out docData);

   var ctext = string.Format("/c cd {1} &&  git add \"{0}\" && git commit \"{0}\" -m  \"autosave {0}\" ", name, SolutionBaseDirectory);
5. Now you'll have `autosave [the file name]` in your git history.

Answer (score 4):

Look at this add-in [Visual Local History](http://vlh2005.codeplex.com/) it is for VS2008 but using adjustment found [here](http://vlh2005.codeplex.com/discussions/217728)   you can use this add-in in VS2010, It works fine for me.
Regards.

Comment: I spent about half an hour trying to get this to work in 2010 before I gave up. It either doesn't work or requires more than half an hour of time to set up.

Comment: Hi jcollum, you dont have "Show Local History" under Tools menu?

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately no such feature for VS2010. The best I can suggest is to either use a full source control system such as SVN or TFS. I have also read that some people have used GIT as a means of local source control, but I cannot comment on this as I've never used GIT before.

Answer (score 0):

you can download this extension.
[Visual Studio History Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AronDCurzon.LocalHistoryforVisualStudio)

And run it, restart your visual studio. Though, it keeps your changes, when you undo any item, that is a change. 
Therefore, it keeps your changes before from undo.